# Not connecting to mongo db

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post("/signup", function (req, res) {
  console.log("first_name: " + req.body.first_name)
  console.log("last_name: " + req.body.last_name)
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err,Client) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("ERROR");}
  else{
    console.log("CONNECTED")
  }

});
  

  res.send("HII")
})
module.exports = router;
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJMp.png)
Here the data is recieved from a form but the function for checking the connection status of mongodb is not working, and no errors are showing

i am a beginer in web devolopment and dont have know much about how its connected and all.

please help me out

Comment: Can you check if your mongodb server is running properly?

Comment: when i enter mongosh

Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.2
Using MongoDB:          7.0.3
Using Mongosh:          2.0.2

it shows like this, seems ok here

but not able to connect in vs code

Comment: Did you specify the database name in your URI string ? I can’t see any database name

Comment: `"ERROR"` is not really a useful error message. Better print `err.message` to see the real problem.

Comment: @SouvanikSaha That's not needed, it defaults to `test`. And you can select the database on statement level.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Make sure that your MongoDB server is running and accessible. You can use the mongosh shell to check the server status. Inside the Mongosh shell run this : db.runCommand({ serverStatus: 1 })

Comment: @SaraM. according above comment, he/she checked this already.

Comment: I have tried all these methods but the outputs are the same

'GET / 304 569.029 ms - -
first_name: JOHN
last_name: PAUL
POST /signup 200 232.939 ms - 3'

Comment: Can you add the details / logs about your MongoDB cnx outside this code using mongosh shell for example

Comment: @SaraM. can you please explain

Comment: can you access your databases in mongoDB ?

Comment: yes, using mongosh

Comment: according to the docs at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.3/classes/MongoClient.html#connect-2 the connect method doesn't take a callback.  Have you tried handling the promise instead?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution is just replace localhost with 127.0.0.1

after that your code will look like :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post("/signup", function (req, res) {
 console.log("first_name: " + req.body.first_name)
 console.log("last_name: " + req.body.last_name)
 MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/{db}", function(err,Client) {
 if(err) {
   console.log("ERROR");}
 else{
   console.log("CONNECTED")
 }

});
 

 res.send("HII")
})
module.exports = router;
```

Conclusion :

When you are using a local mongodb database, you must be write a **local ip** (***127.0.0.1***) instead of **localhost** in code when you are connecting a database

Comment: this is not true

Answer (score -1):

Try this code once :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// Define MongoDB URL and Database Name
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'your_database_name'; //Enter your database name here

// Function to establish connection
async function connectToDB() {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    return client.db(dbName);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err);
    throw err;
  }
}

// Establish MongoDB connection when the server starts
connectToDB()
  .then(() => console.log("Backend connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB during server start:", err));

// GET home page
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.post("/signup", async function (req, res) {
  console.log("first_name: " + req.body.first_name);
  console.log("last_name: " + req.body.last_name);



  res.send("User signed up successfully");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/submit',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shibili',function(err,client){
    if(err)
    console.log('error')
    else
    console.log('database connected')
  
  })
  

  res.send("got it")
})

module.exports = router;
```